# Proof of Thevenin's and Norton's Theorem?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Googling this gave me a number of proofs, but almost all of them assume the load is a linear component.

Could someone give me a proof for these theorems assuming the load can be *anything* (a linear or non-linear component)?

Comment: When you say "anything" do you mean any _linear_ circuit element or do you mean absolutely anything? I don't think these theorems apply to non-linear circuits.

Comment: @JoeHass I mean absolutely anything. The theorems don't apply to non-linear circuits, but they do apply to linear circuits with non-linear loads.

Comment: Could you link to a statement of the theorem itself and the proof you find unsatisfactory? The statement of the theorem on Wikipedia, for example, says nothing about the load, so I don't see how the proof of the theorem depends on what the load is.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think the issue revolves around the use of the superposition principle. The complete network has non-linear components, thus it isn't clear if the superposition principle applies to the linear subset of that complete network or not.

Comment: From my answer to op's other question, "basically one way to state Thevenin's theorem is that the I-V characteristic of any one-terminal network of independent sources and linear elements will be a straight line." It doesn't matter what is attached to the port, the characteristic of the linear network is still a straight line. I'm not sure how to go further into answering this question without seeing the specifics of the proof you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 3):

Let there be some *linear* circuit in a black box with two terminals exposed.

We measure the open circuit voltage \$V_{OC}\$ and the short circuit current \$I_{SC}\$ at the two terminals.

Now, according to [Thevenin's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem#A_proof_of_the_theorem) *[theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem)*, the voltage across the terminals is given by

$$V_O = V_{OC} - I_O \frac{V_{OC}}{I_{SC}} = V_{TH} - I_OR_{TH}$$

Remember, *this result is derived without an assumption as to the functional IV relationship for the load*.

The above equation for \$V_O\$ is a [load line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_line_%28electronics%29) and, *whether the load is linear or not*, the solution is the intersection of the load line and the IV curve of the load.

For example:

[image]

In equation form, let the load be some not necessarily linear circuit element where

$$V_L = V_O = f(I_L) $$

Then, it follows that

$$f(I_L) = V_{TH} - I_L R_{TH}$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain the difference between \$V_O\$ and \$V_{OC}\$? With a load, \$V_O\$ is the voltage across the load, but if you don't have a load, (and just have open terminals) aren't \$V_O\$ and \$V_{OC}\$ the same?

Comment: @dfg, \$V_O\$ is a voltage variable for the voltage across the terminals.  \$V_{OC}\$ is the *value* of the voltage variable \$V_O\$ when the \$I_O = 0\$, i.e., when the load is an open circuit.