# How can we understand the motivaton and the derivation of Thevenin theorem from scratch?

Tags: thevenin

There are many questions on this site abut the Thevenin's theorem. The closest question I found: [Proof of Thevenin's and Norton's Theorem?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106377/proof-of-thevenins-and-nortons-theoremser) but I dont understand anything from the answer.

In books and tutorials I always find such definitions: "Thevenin’s Theorem states that any linear circuit containing several voltages and resistances can be replaced by just one single voltage in series with a single resistance connected across the load" Sources should be independent ect ect..

Wikipedia says superposition theorem is employed.

Im wondering if this theorem is so simple why no one is explaining it step by step from scratch starting from the motivation.

I dont want to memorize this theorem without understanding how and why it was derived at least as a big picture.

Lets say we have a black box a network and we have input output ports with sources attached to this unknown network. How can we logically derive Thevenin theorem from this point? Theorem involves superposition theorem, linearity, being independent source and Kirchhoff's laws.

Some says Thevenin’s theorem is a direct consequence of the Superposition theorem.

Is there  a way to explain the concept in a simple fashion?

Comment: Not just superposition, but also homogeneity, as well. The definition of "linear" requires both of these. Are you wanting a simple math exposition here? Or verbal hand-waving? To prove the theorem, I think, you actually need the math starting points and then a progression from there. But it's your question.

Comment: You can first have a look at [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/231583/87069). You can find a proof of the Thévenin's theorem in the text cited in the answer.

Comment: @jonk what i mean is step by step demonstration from scratch by using an example with some resistors, two voltage sources and a current source. for a person who knows about kirchoff laws and superposition concept. for example asap in a circuit all independent sources have a contribution to a particular resistance's voltage. so how can we proceed from here to derive the thevenin? for example the answer below does not help since it is only verbal and no examples and no use of superposition ect. i dont get anything from such explanations.

Comment: I didn't get anything from it, either. Hmm. I have an idea how to approach this that is intuitive but also demonstrable with an actual circuit. Maybe I'll take a shot.

Comment: Looks like someone else gave it a shot. I added a comment there. Let me know if I'm wrong or right. If it's good enough, I won't bother adding more to the pile.

Comment: @jonk you are right that answer is not a logical step by step demonstration either. its also very foggy. i myself dont understand. it doesn't go to the core and give an actual example and demonstrate how superposition yileds  thevenin theorem. im disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

It is natural to think of constant voltage sources, since there are so many around, such as batteries and power supplies. For learning purposes, assume that they all have some internal resistance. This is the first lesson in electrical modeling: add an ideal resistor to an ideal voltage source to make a better model for a real voltage source such as a battery.

Adding a resistor in series creates a new voltage node that is internal to the source. This new node can be inconvenient during circuit analysis. The Norton equivalent is a way to get rid of this extra node, and instead use a model with an ideal current source and a resistor. This analysis trick becomes more important when analyzing circuits in a systematic way, such as with matrix math.

For example, the voltage from a 9V battery with 36 Ohms of internal resistance can also be modeled as a 36 Ohm resistor in parallel with a 0.25 Amp current source. This makes some types of circuit analysis easier.

If someone built a battery using a real current source this way, it would get hot. Without any load, the 36 Ohm resistor would dissipate power P = I<sup>2</sup>R =  0.25<sup>2</sup>*36 = 2.25 Watts.

If someone claims that in a black box you can't tell if you have a Norton current source or a Thevenin voltage source, ask if you can have one of each, and then measure the temperature difference between them! This detail is left out of many texts, and claims of true equivalence of these circuits are misleading. Instead of motivating this theorem, perhaps it is better to demotivate it and reduce it to a circuit analysis trick.

Constant current sources are less common in everyday life, but there are some around, and they can also be translated to voltage sources for computational convenience.

Answer (score 1):

For the theorem as given in your post we need to show that we can replace an arbitrary network consisting of independent sources and resistors by an independent voltage source and a resistor.

The first step is to use a fixed current source as a load. If we had another load, like a resistor we could replace it by a current source that's equal to the current through the load without changing the circuit, so a current source is fine.

[image]

Looking at the left picture we have a network (shown as a box) containing some sources and single current source. The voltage between the terminal is \$v_1\$, it is a result of the sources of the network and the current source.

Using superposition we can calculate this voltage. First we remove the current source and leave the sources of the network active. We get a voltage \$e_{oc}\$ (oc for open circuit) between the two terminals. Then we set all the source of the network to zero and consider only the current source. Since the network consists only of resistors an equivalent resistance \$R_{eq}\$ can be calculated. The voltage across the terminals due to the current source alone is \$R_{eq} (-i)\$.

Combining the two contributions gives \$v_1 = e_{oc} - R_{eq} \cdot i\$. This equation describes a voltage source with a series resistor, the Thevenin equivalent network.

Not all networks have a thevenin equivalent, it is required that the loaded network has a unique solution. The load can be arbitrary (e.g. non-linear).

The Thevenin theorem actually is more general an can include linear elements like, resistors, capacitors, inductors and controlled sources.

Comment: One can't Thevenize an ideal current source nor Nortonize an ideal voltage source. Also, I think the OP wants to _understand_ superposition and how it applies. Not merely _apply_ rules that were formed from the idea. Wants to see _how_ those rules flow out of the motivation. By comparison, imagine Newton's "all particles of matter attract all other particles of matter" as a motivation. Then imagining how one goes from that _concept_, and the idea of an inverse square law with light, to rigorously deducing a quantifying equation: \$F=G\cdot\frac{m_1\cdot m_2}{r^2}\$.

Comment: "One can't Thevenize an ideal current source nor Nortonize an ideal voltage source." That's why I wrote: "Not all networks have a thevenin equivalent."

Comment: Yeah. Just making sure it was called out in a different way, calling out two specifics to make the concept slightly more concrete.